# Magento - Check if item has specific custom option or not in shopping cart

Tags: php, magento

In my shopping cart page i need to be able to check if any added products have a particular custom option set on them - in this case a custom option called 'age_guide'.

If so i need to add a small disclaimer text line. How would i go about doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your custom option set on a product is **age_guide**, then in your

```
template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
```

around line 46

```
<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_option['label']) ?>
```

Use below code:

```
<?php if($_option['label'] =='age_guide'): // or whatever your custom option label ?>
     <div>
       <span><?php echo $this->__('Your Disclaimer Text Goes Here');?></span>
     </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```